# LiveData how to get the number of copies?

Tags: android, android-livedata, mutablelivedata

I have an app with multiple fragments in ViewPager.
There are RecyclerViews with data that may be repeated in other fragments.
So i decided to use one MutableLiveData for each unit (using a unique key),
without extra copy, in one repository

Data in livedata like that:

```
class Data {
    var id = 0
    var type = 0
    var name = ""
    var onlineStatus = OnlineStatus.GroupOrWithout
    var icon: Bitmap: ?= null
}

map[data.id + data.type] = Data()

// when we need this data
fun getData(id: Int, type: Int) : MutableLiveData<Data>? {
    val res = map[id + type]
    if(res != null) {
        return res
    }
    // or create new one if this fist time when we need it
    ....
}
```

But now i realized, that the traditional approach with LiveData limited to fragment's lifecycle.
has the advantage that is destroys unused data after the fragment is destroyed.
But this way looks more complicated to me, because events in another fragment
may be lost and then i will have not-synchronous data even of the same element.

So I was thinking, can I manually manipulate and destroy the MutableLiveData,
if it has no references from fragments?

Probably in the android is an analogue of shared_ptr from c++?
I really like current architecture but i don't know how to clean not used more LiveData

Comment: Can you post fragment's code , please ?

Comment: In fragment is just call getData(id, type) and set result to binding of the fragment